# WPF - animate progress bar according to time

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm looking to animate a progress, so that it takes 1 minute to complete a cycle. My code is:

```
ProgressBar _progressSec = new ProgressBar();
_progressSec.Name = "_progressSec";
_progressSec.Minimum = 0;
_progressSec.Maximum = 60;
_progressSec.Value = DateTime.Now.Second;
this.RegisterName(_progressSec.Name, _progressSec);

NewGrid.Children.Add(_progressSec);

Storyboard newStory = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation newAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
newAnimation.To = 60;
newAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Second);
newAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
newAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
newStory.Children.Add(newAnimation);

Storyboard.SetTarget(newAnimation, _progressSec);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newAnimation, new PropertyPath(ProgressBar.ValueProperty));

newStory.Begin();
```

This bar takes exactly 1 minute to complete a cycle, which is not exactly what I want. So if I start it at 40 seconds, it'll take a minute to reach 60 seconds.

What I'd like it to do is to start at the current seconds value, increment each second, and when it reaches 60 seconds, start again, so if it starts at 40 seconds it takes 20 seconds to reach a minute.
When it reaches a minute, I'd like it to start again (at 0). Of course, I could have just said I'm developing a clock/timer, but thought I'd better explain what was happening when I run the code.

When I add a From value to newAnimation, it always starts at that value, not at the BeginTime value.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The way you're setting `BeginTime` is wrong.  It specifies at what time in the future does the animation start. And `new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Second)` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want your animation to take some other time than one minute, you have to tell it so:

```
int from = 50;
int to = 60;
newAnimation.From = from;
newAnimation.To = to;
newAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(to - from));
```

Comment: The first animation will be less than a minute (depending on when it starts) - each animation after that will be for a minute.

Comment: Thanks svick - the code works in that in the first minute it takes the correct amount to time to complete a cycle. However, after that it always start at the same point (where it started the first time). How do I get it to start the second and subsequent cycle at 0 and take 1 minute to complete?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to svick, I worked out how to do it. Solution is below:

```
    ProgressBar _progressSec = new ProgressBar();
    DoubleAnimation newAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    Storyboard newStory = new Storyboard();

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progressSec.Name = "_progressSec";
        _progressSec.Minimum = 0;
        _progressSec.Maximum = 59;
        _progressSec.Value = DateTime.Now.Second;
        this.RegisterName(_progressSec.Name, _progressSec);

        NewGrid.Children.Add(_progressSec);

        int from = DateTime.Now.Second;
        int to = 59;
        newAnimation.From = from;
        newAnimation.To = to;
        newAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(to - from));

        newStory.Completed += new EventHandler(story_Completed);
        newStory.Children.Add(newAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(newAnimation, _progressSec);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newAnimation, new PropertyPath(ProgressBar.ValueProperty));

        newStory.Begin();
    }

    void story_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int from2 = 0;
        int to2 = 59;
        newAnimation.From = from2;
        newAnimation.To = to2;
        newAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        newStory.Children.Add(newAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(newAnimation, _progressSec);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newAnimation, new PropertyPath(ProgressBar.ValueProperty));

        newStory.Begin();
    }
```